# Could not initialize class net.minidev.json.JSONUtil

Tags: java

WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver Line:199 -
Resolved [org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.minidev.json.JSONUtil]

Comment: Please provide a bit more context for the problem. There is a tutorial on how to ask each question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.